# Do we need the low-light tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [low-light](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-light) tag only has two questions, both of which are from 2012.

It seems like [this one](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-plants-survive-in-a-relatively-dark-room) could be replaced by [light](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light), which I added.

[This](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/what-can-i-grow-in-a-sealed-office-environment-with-no-natural-light-or-airflow) already has 
[light](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light), so I think it's redundant.

The tag has no description, so do you think we should get rid of it, or perhaps make it a synonym of [light](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light)?

Comment: Good question! I was going to post almost the same, except with [tag:shade] as the synonym.

Comment: I'm glad you agree. I totally forgot about shade!

Comment: Partial shade is the more appropriate term.  It will coincide with Western Garden Book...and all plant tags that I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed. I went through and re-tagged both, that should get rid of it shortly.